# Get all value of one row on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `html` table which is created dynamically.

```
Name Value Option
1      2     3
4      5     6
7      8     9
```

Now I click on the `option 3` I should see alert `1 and 2`
similarly if I click `6` I should get `4 and 5` in alert box

How to do this ?

sample Code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="approve">2</td>
        <td class="">3</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="approve">5</td>
        <td class="">6</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td class="approve">8</td>
        <td class="">9</td>
    <tr>
</table>




$(".approve").click(function() {
    alert($(".approve").val);
});
```

Comment: Here's a [Javascript tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) and a [jQuery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/). They contain everything you need to know.

Comment: I know how js, jquery works i need the code or algorithm for this current scenario

Comment: We don't have a code writing service here, have a go yourself and ask a question if you get stuck (if you're stuck right at the beginning, you need to visit the tutorials)

Comment: "Sample code" should be the things you've tried.

Comment: I tried one which only gives me the value of first row. it does not give the value of other row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    //var prev = $(this).parent().find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)').text();
    var prev = $(this).parent().find('td').not($(this)).text();
    alert(prev);
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxz5u/1/)

Comment: nothing wrong with that...if you are using this class for another elements too than you can select specific elements like this.

Comment: You can also use the `siblings` function with `td` as parameter to get all the td's under the same parent.

Comment: @UntraDe: asker don't want the data of all td, asker only want the data of previous two td.

Answer (score 3):

You probably better off learning this stuffs yourself because you wont be able to request code here every time you encounter a problem. I suggest you to go learn JQuery here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp and more specifically to your task, the click event: http://api.jquery.com/click/ and the `siblings` function which allows you to find the siblings of a given element: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: you could just say siblings function that would have been enough for me. i dont understand why you are all being so rune

Comment: @LynAs I'm sorry if it seems like I'm being rude, but I just want to teach you to use the vast references and tutorials that exists on the internet which most of the time will solve your problem in no time. This is an important part of being a programmer today, if you will know how to read and search solutions in references you will be able to solve most of your problem by yourself.

Comment: Like i said already i tried to find solution by myself could not get the result so i posted the question. And I did mention code `or Algorithm ` why are u stuck on the code part. thanks for ur answer

Comment: @LynAs I apologize if I offended you, I'm just trying to help you understand that if you just try to think about it step by step like: how can I capture a click event? how can I find elements relative to the element I clicked on?. You can solve this kind of problems by yourself in no time.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<table>
<tr><td class="approve">1</td><td class="approve">2</td><td class="test" onclick="return get(this)">3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="approve">4</td><td class="approve">5</td><td class="test" onclick="return get(this)">6</td></tr>
<tr><td class="approve">7</td><td class="approve">8</td><td class="test" onclick="return get(this)">9</td></tr>
</table>



    function get(thID) {
var sVal = ""
           $(thID).parent().find('td.approve').each(function () {

               sVal  = sVal  + " " + $(this).html();

           });
      alert(sVal)

       }
```

Comment: ohhhhhh why use inline JS?

Comment: Ohhh I just want to show simplest version in the sense that he does not know much about jquery.. may be it is wrong approach...

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
    var values = [];

    $.each($(this).siblings(), function() {
        values.push($(this).text());
    });

    alert(values.join(" "));

});
```

**Resources:**

- https://api.jquery.com/on/
- https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

**jsFiddle:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cm9me/1/)**

Comment: why code it all out for him?

Comment: @doppel I felt like doing so ;)

Comment: to downvoters: please provide feedback

Comment: You just provide him with the solution without explaining him how you figured it out, so he can do it himself next time.

Comment: i added links to resources

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).on("click", "td.option", function()
{   
    var second = $(this).prev();
    var first = second.prev();
    alert("First: "+first.text()+", Second: "+second.text());
});
```

EDIt: what is bad with my solution ??